# How to hide this navigation menu when its hover event is not triggered anymore?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a small navigation menu which opens when its hover event is called. When I choose an item in the menu its current item changes to the chosen item and the menu disappears. So far so good. Now what I would like to achieve is that the menu also disappears when I don't choose any item and I just move the mouse to somewhere else. I've made an example on jsFiddle: [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5XCj/4/)

I've already tried `blur()`, first of all it doesn't work and second of all I want the menu to disappear already when the hover is gone and not after someone has clicked somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you should use `.on()` instead of `.live()` as of jQuery 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I rewrote it to work the way it's intended...

`.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and .`on()` should be used in favor of this. However, hover isn't supported with a callback in .on(), so we use mouseover and mouseout events in a chain to replicate the same idea as a callback function.

Also, moved around the elements and added a span to handle our 'text' update.

[Here's the jSfiddle. Note changes in all AREAS: CSS, HTML & jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/f5XCj/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mouseout`:

```
$('.small-nav-left').live('mouseout', function() {
        $('.small-nav-menu-left').hide();
    });
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5XCj/6/).

Comment: This doesn't work. The menu is gone before I even have the time to click on something.

Comment: @Loolooii It's because of the way that you've built the menu in CSS, which is a question entirely of it's own.

Comment: I would recommend rebuilding this drop down, with pure CSS

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, you think I should make the "button" part of the whole menu? I don't think that will make this easier. And do you think there's no other way to achieve this without changing the way I did the CSS and HTML?

Comment: @Andy, that was what I did first and you're right now I see that was a better way to do this.

Comment: @Loolooii No, there isn't any way to do this like that. the Hover event expects the event to stay within the parent element when you move your mouse into another element. If it moves into an element that is NOT within the constraints of the parent element, then it will immediately invoke the function. You need to move the outer closing `small-nav` </div> tag to contain all the elements you plan on having be part of the menu.